# Sort JSON values?

Tags: ruby, json

I have a JSON list like:

```
response = '{"ContainsErrors":false,"Result":[{"Name":"Aegypten","IsoCode":"EG"},{"Name":"Aequatorialguinea","IsoCode":"GQ"},{"Name":"Aethiopien","IsoCode":"ET"},{"Name":"Afghanistan","IsoCode":"AF"},{"Name":"Albanien","IsoCode":"AL"},{"Name":"Algerien","IsoCode":"DZ"},{"Name":"Angola","IsoCode":"AO"},{"Name":"Antigua und Barbuda","IsoCode":"AG"},{"Name":"Argentinien","IsoCode":"AR"},{"Name":"Australien","IsoCode":"AU"},{"Name":"Bahamas","IsoCode":"BS"}]}'
```

How can I get it sorted after names?

```
response.sort_by { |k, v| v["Name"] }
```

doesn't work.

What does work is:

```
response = RestClient.get("#{Settings.itineris.url}/de/RepInfo/#{action}")
#response = '{"ContainsErrors":false,"Result":[{"Name":"Aegypten","IsoCode":"EG"},{"Name":"Aequatorialguinea","IsoCode":"GQ"},{"Name":"Aethiopien","IsoCode":"ET"},{"Name":"Afghanistan","IsoCode":"AF"},{"Name":"Albanien","IsoCode":"AL"},{"Name":"Algerien","IsoCode":"DZ"},{"Name":"Angola","IsoCode":"AO"},{"Name":"Antigua und Barbuda","IsoCode":"AG"},{"Name":"Argentinien","IsoCode":"AR"},{"Name":"Australien","IsoCode":"AU"},{"Name":"Bahamas","IsoCode":"BS"}]}'

JSON.load(response)['Result']
```

The result is an unsorted List. How can I get an ordered list of country names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a string in response. Before operating on it, you should convert it to `Hash`:

```
response = '{"ContainsErrors":false,"Result":[{"Name":"Aegypten","IsoCode":"EG"}]}'
require 'json'
hash = JSON.parse(response)
```

and then do whatever you want:

```
hash['Result'].sort_by { |v| v["Name"] }
#                         ⇑ v here since it’s an array of hashes
```

To get an ordered list of country names:

```
hash['Result'].map { |v| v["Name"] }.sort
```

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work and so i tried with JSON.load(response)['Result'].sort_by { |k, v| v["Name"] } but it failed, too.

Comment: Did you noticed that I concatenated your input in my example to fit the page width?

Comment: @Michael i use Ruby 1.9.3 and the error is "NoMethodError" and `block in rest_request', 'each', `sort_by' ...

Comment: @ArupRakshit that’s nonsense. `require` doesn’t need to be on top.

Comment: @StandardNerd Updated my answer for sorted **country list**.

Comment: @ArupRakshit what if you need to `require` smth depending on condition? Have you never seen `if 'win' ; require '_win' ; else require '_nix' ; end` ?